# Оцифровка горизонталей на карте местности

Tags: карты, распознавание-образов, трассировка

Есть задача: проложить трассу на карте местности, избегая большого разброса в высотах. Проблема в том, чтобы определить этот самый разброс по карте-рисунку, оцифровать горизонтали, построить профиль высот. Как распознать горизонталь как объект и определить его высоту? На карте может присутствовать множество других объектов, таких как: реки, озера, различные сооружения, здания. С распознаванием почти не знаком, прошу дать вектор для поиска решения, литературу может какую или ссылки для изучения этой темы(а может есть альтернативные решения, буду рад всему)

Comment: нашел сайт с наглядным описанием моей задачи http://www.vhfdx.ru/altitude_map.html

Comment: Для реализации того, что показано в "наглядном описании", достаточно пройти дугу большого круга между точками с неким шагом, на каждом шаге выдавая высоту. Задача же ваша похожа на проведение трассы по изолинии, если перепад небольшой.

Comment: @MBo , вы правы, в частности, мне нужно научить программу различать эти изолинии и подписи к ним(высоты) для дальнейшей оцифровки.